# How to display multiple radio buttons in ReactJs using map( ) function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display multiple radio buttons which has 2 buttons on the right end. The value for the radio buttons are mentioned in the state as follows:

```
 this.state = {
        email: ['abc.gmail.com','def.gmail.com','No email alerts']
     };
```

The number of radio buttons depends on the number of 'email' values in state.So, in my render function I have called the `<RadioGroup />` component which is already designed in my project and trying to display the radio buttons. The code for the same look like this:

```
import RadioGroup from '../../../../Common/CommonComponents/radioButton.js';

class EmailComp extends React.Component {

render() {
  return(
   <div>
      {this.state.options.map((emails)  =>  <div>
         <div className={classes.scePasswordOptionContainer} aria-label='Email Container'>
                <div className={classes.sceBorderContainer + ' row'}>
                    <RadioGroup 
                        options={[this.state.options[0]]}
                        type='radio'
                        validStyle={this.state.selectedOptionValidStyle}
                        selectedOptions={this.state.selectedOptions}
                        radioOutLineFlag={this.state.radioOutline}
                        onClick={(event) => this.onRadioClick(event, 0)}
                        onFocus={(event) => this.onRadioFocus(event, 0)}
                        onBlur={this.onRadioBlur}
                        />
                </div>

            <div className={classes.sceFullButtonContainer + ' row'}>
              {/* <div className={this.props.data.emailDrawer.isDrawerOpen ? classes.sceDisplayNothing : void (0)}> */}
                <div className={classes.scePasswordButtonContainer}>
                  <div className=' col-xs-2'>
                    <button
                      id='cancelEmail'
                      className={classes.sceDeleteButton}
                      tabIndex='0'
                      onClick={this.onCancelClick}
                    >
                      <i className={'far fa-times-circle fa-lg'} />
                    </button>
                    <button
                      id='editEmail'
                      tabIndex='0'
                      aria-label='Edit Email'
                      className={classes.sceEditButton}
                      onClick={this.props.handleEmailToggle} >
                      <i className='fas fa-pencil-alt fa-lg sce-fontColor-white' />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              {/* </div> */}
            </div>
        </div>

        <p className={classes.radio}> &nbsp; </p></div>)}
   </div>
 );
}
}
```

Now, I am not able to figure out how to change the content of the radio button content. What is happening currently is the label has only the value of index 0, i.e. 'abc.gmail.com' .So, all the 3 radio buttons are showing **abc.gmail.com**. So, how to get all the 3 values from the map function in the radio buttons?

Comment: What is the value of `this.state.options`?

Comment: @MithunGS its the value of the email array in the state. I wrote it as options by mistake here.